# Alarm when device hasn't been touched by user in x hours?

Tags: android, android-alarms

Is there a way to get an alarm to fire some time after the user has last touched the device? i.e. when the device has been in the users pocket for a while, or when the user is sleeping.

I need to do a db-locking update for 2 minutes every few days, preferably when the user doesn't want to use the app.

Edit:
I have no clue when the user will not be using the app, since it's something that will be used anytime during the day, just before going to bed and just after waking up.

Currently I'm just picking a random time between 07:00 and 08:00 every 3 days (using AlarmManager, restarting on boot, etc), hoping that the user doesn't really need this feature at that time of day, but I'm pretty sure someone will.

Comment: Props for keeping the user experience a positive one.  =)

Comment: look in to android Motion sensors, i think you can check device movements with Accelerometer or maybe another sensor, then perform a task in response to an event from the sensor  you will monitor. hope this helps...

Comment: What if the user touched or used the device but not the app... what should happen? Since we don't know that is critical for you and nothing about the app, the question is a little vague...

Comment: just when the user isn't using the app would suffice